# How to send data from one widget to multiple widgets while Navigating in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer

Actually I was working on a GoogleSignIn button, where when signed in, I am navigating and sending data to another widget/page for the Drawer. What I want is that this accessed data from google should be sent to all other drawers built in scaffold for my entire app. I know there is a better approach for Global drawer, but having different drawers for each of my scaffold is my app's requirement.

This is the first widget's code:

```
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        RestaurantHome(detailsUser: details)));
```

This is code of where I'm getting data using constructor for other widget.

```
  class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser;

  Home({Key key, this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
```

In above scenario, I'm only able to send data to Home class using constructor. But I actually want to send data to multiple classes for accessing drawer details there while navigating at once.
Please guide me the best approach in this problem.
Think of me as a beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could provide your user details class by the entire app, a recommend using get_it(https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) to that

you create a class like:

```dart
class AuthController {
 UserDetails detailsUser;
}
```

on login function:

```dart
void login() {
  /// do whatherver you want
  getIt<AuthController>().detailsUser = details;
}
```

on anywhere in your app

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser = getIt<AuthController>().detailsUser;

  Home();

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
```

so this way you can acess the user details in any of your drawers.
just take a look at get_it documentation to see how to configure it, it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing with redux ,provider,bloc. there is multiple to get data in any where in app.
If you want to create  this pattern I can help your.